# Array to include macro variable in SAS

Tags: arrays, sas, do-loops

I would like to sum up and create & rates, each month of data is a column in my dataset. I want to have a dataset with the rate and sum for each month at the end. I currently run this code to create some calculations:

```
PROC SQL;
CREATE TABLE WANT AS 
SELECT 
 (SUM(ROLL_&mmmyy2) /SUM(ACCOUNTS_&mmmyy2))*100 AS &mmmyy2
,(SUM(ROLL_&mmmyy3) /SUM(ACCOUNTS_&mmmyy3))*100 AS &mmmyy3
,(SUM(ROLL_&mmmyy4) /SUM(ACCOUNTS_&mmmyy4))*100 AS &mmmyy4
,(SUM(ROLL_&mmmyy5) /SUM(ACCOUNTS_&mmmyy5))*100 AS &mmmyy5
,(SUM(ROLL_&mmmyy6) /SUM(ACCOUNTS_&mmmyy6))*100 AS &mmmyy6
,(SUM(ROLL_&mmmyy7) /SUM(ACCOUNTS_&mmmyy7))*100 AS &mmmyy7
,(SUM(ROLL_&mmmyy8) /SUM(ACCOUNTS_&mmmyy8))*100 AS &mmmyy8
,(SUM(ROLL_&mmmyy9) /SUM(ACCOUNTS_&mmmyy9))*100 AS &mmmyy9
,(SUM(ROLL_&mmmyy10) /SUM(ACCOUNTS_&mmmyy10))*100 AS &mmmyy10
,(SUM(ROLL_&mmmyy11) /SUM(ACCOUNTS_&mmmyy11))*100 AS &mmmyy11
,(SUM(ROLL_&mmmyy12) /SUM(ACCOUNTS_&mmmyy12))*100 AS &mmmyy12
,(SUM(ROLL_&mmmyy13) /SUM(ACCOUNTS_&mmmyy13))*100 AS &mmmyy13
,(SUM(ROLL_&mmmyy14) /SUM(ACCOUNTS_&mmmyy14))*100 AS &mmmyy14

,SUM(ROLL_&mmmyy2) AS SUM_&mmmyy2
,SUM(ROLL_&mmmyy3) AS SUM_&mmmyy3
,SUM(ROLL_&mmmyy4) AS SUM_&mmmyy4
,SUM(ROLL_&mmmyy5) AS SUM_&mmmyy5
,SUM(ROLL_&mmmyy6) AS SUM_&mmmyy6
,SUM(ROLL_&mmmyy7) AS SUM_&mmmyy7
,SUM(ROLL_&mmmyy8) AS SUM_&mmmyy8
,SUM(ROLL_&mmmyy9) AS SUM_&mmmyy9
,SUM(ROLL_&mmmyy10) AS SUM_&mmmyy10
,SUM(ROLL_&mmmyy11) AS SUM_&mmmyy11
,SUM(ROLL_&mmmyy12) AS SUM_&mmmyy12
,SUM(ROLL_&mmmyy13) AS SUM_&mmmyy13
,SUM(ROLL_&mmmyy14) AS SUM_&mmmyy14

FROM HAVE;
QUIT;
```

The &mmmyy(number) macros are all dates.

Is there a way to simplify this, I'm currently trying:

```
DATA WANT;
SET HAVE;
ARRAY ROLL_&&MMMYY[12] ROLL_&&MMMYY2-ROLL_&&MMMYY14; 
ARRAY ACCOUNTS_&&MMMYY[12] ACCOUNT&&MMMYY2-ACCOUNT&&MMMYY14;
DO I = 2 TO 14;
&&MMMYY[I]= (SUM(ROLL_&&MMMYY[I])/SUM(ACCOUNTS_&&MMMYY[I]))*100;
END;
RUN;
```

This is an example of how the data looks:

```
Account Number  ROLL_Jun23  Roll_May23  Roll_Apr23  Roll_Mar23 Accounts_Jun23   Accounts_May23  Accounts_Apr23  Accounts_Mar23
1                  1            0           0           0           1                   1           1                 1
2                  0            1           1           0           1                   1           0                 0
3                  0            0           0           0           1                   0           0                 0
4                  1            1           1           1           1                   1           1                 0
5                  1            1           1           1           1                   1           1                 0
6                  1            1           0           0           1                   1           0                 0
```

The idea of my array is that I would end up with data like:

```
Jun23        May23        Apr23        Mar23        
66.67        80.00        100.00       200.00
```

Comment: There is definitely a simpler way. Please provide a minimum of sample data for us to work with. Makes it easier to provide a usable code answer.

Comment: Forget the macro variables, what are the names of the actual variables?

Comment: @PeterClemmensen I've added a sample of the data to the question, Tom you will see the name of the columns within the sample too.

Comment: Can you also post the output data you would want for the small example data you showed?  I'm not understanding it yet, but the usual advice to make this easier to code would be to transpose it into a vertical dataset with columns AccountNumber, Month, Roll, and Accounts.  So make each month a row instead of a column.

Comment: @Quentin I've posted the final dataset I need. Thanks

Comment: Why is May23 66.67? Should it not be 80.00 (4/5). What about Apr23? 100%=3/3, and Mar23 is 200% (2/1)

Comment: @Richard Apologies for the typos I've cleaned this up now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should treat data as data, and thus I emphasize using a pivot strategy to take the dates out of the variable names.

Use a reporting procedure such as TABULATE or REPORT to present summaries of your now categorical data.

Example:

A DATA step view is used to pivot the data for use in TABULATE.

```
data have;
 input Account_Number ROLL_Jun23 Roll_May23 Roll_Apr23 Roll_Mar23 Accounts_Jun23 Accounts_May23 Accounts_Apr23 Accounts_Mar23;
 datalines;
1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1
2 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0
3 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
4 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0
5 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0
6 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0
;

data flags / view=flags;
  set have;
  array rolls roll_:;
  array accounts accounts_:;
  do over rolls;
    date = input('01'||scan(vname(rolls),2,'_'),date7.);
    roll_flag = rolls;
    acct_flag = accounts;
    output;
  end;
  format date monyy5.;
  keep account_number date roll_flag acct_flag;
run;

proc tabulate data=flags;
  class account_number;
  class date / descending;
  var roll_flag acct_flag;
  table 
    date='Month' * (roll_flag='Roll' acct_flag='Acct') * f=5. * sum='';
  ;
run;
```

Results

```
-------------------------------------------------
|                     Month                     |
|-----------------------------------------------|
|   JUN23   |   MAY23   |   APR23   |   MAR23   |
|-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------|
|Roll |Acct |Roll |Acct |Roll |Acct |Roll |Acct |
|-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----|
|    4|    6|    4|    5|    3|    3|    2|    1|
-------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thanks for this. But I don't see how I get the % I need using this method? I think I can edit it a bit to get what I want though thank you.

Comment: That's the beauty of data in categorical form, little or no need for macro at all.

Answer (score 2):

The best thing to do is not to place data, dates in this case, into metadata, the names of variables.  If you just restructure the data to have three variables and N observations instead of 2*N variables then you have not reason to use macro code to generate code.  Now your key variables become ACCOUNT_NUMBER and DATE and your data variables become just ROLL and ACCOUNTS and you could use SQL more easily.

```
 select date
      , sum(roll) as roll_sum
      , sum(accounts) as accounts_sum
      , calculated roll_sum/calculated accounts_sum as average
   from have
   group by date 
 ;
```

If you do want to use ARRAY you probably need to first take the SUM of the values.

```
proc summary data=have ;
   var roll_: accounts_: ;
   output out=summary sum= ;
run;
```

Now your arrays could look like:

```
data want;
  set summary;
  array roll roll_:;
  array accounts accounts_: ;
  do index=1 to dim(roll);
     length date $5;
     date = scan(vname(roll[index]),-1,'_');
     roll_sum = roll[index];
     account_sum = accounts[index];
     average = roll_sum/account_sum ;
     output;
  end;
  keep index date roll_sum account_sum average;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer, Sorry I'm not sure I understand it. As this wouldn't allow me to have the calculation per month would it? I'm not sure I can easily restructure the data you see.

Comment: Tom gave two different solutions.  If you reshape the data (using code like the view in Richard's answer), then you can use the PROC SQL step with group by date.  If you don't want to reshape the data, then you can use the PROC SUMMARY step and DATA WANT step. WANT will have monthly average variables.

Comment: Thanks Quentin, I've used Richard's method below to reshape the data which has worked great. Thanks for everyone's help, really helped to re-think the shape like you all said.